# Applying multiple filters to the state in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders three multi-select boxes (Name, Job, Car) and a data grid. The user can select multiple options in the three filters that would then filter the data grid too.

First, I fetch the data from the remote server in an `useEffect` block and data grid renders without any filters applied. Next, the user can then select one (or two or three) filters which would then update the data grid. I have an `onChange` function for each filter that updates the data grid. Here's how I am filtering my data grid.

```
const onChange = () => filterbyName(filterByJob(filterByCar(data)))
```

where `data` is the data I fetched at the time of initial component loading.

I have to apply three filters together as any time the user selects any one option e.g. Job, the selected job(s) filters are now saved in the state. The same goes for Name and Car.

My question is how do I avoid three nested function calls, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Hi, using `selectors` might be useful for your use case. I'd go for https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect which is really a great selector lib

Answer (score 0):

what is inside the filterbyName, filterbyJob and filterbyCar functions?

if you're calling api each time user selects new filter, you can pass the selected filter to the api

but if you're only updating given data, put api data in state, and in your render method filter the data based on the selected filter
here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-payne-e0261